# In ROS network, when does a topic really transported?

Tags: ros, network

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In a ROS system run across different computers in a network, when does a topic really being transported? Let's say in computer A, I publish 100 topics.. Do all the topics transported to all ROS device in the network? Or only the ROS nodes in different computers subscribed to a subset of topics should those subset of topics be transported??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/184422/in-ros-network,-when-does-a-topic-really-transported?/) by [Xegara](https://answers.ros.org/users/14401/xegara/) on ROS Answers with karma: 52 on 2014-07-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Only the topics that are actually subscribed to from a different computer are transferred over the network.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3